# SharePoint List items dropdown value automatically changes when edited

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I've encountered a very weird behavior when editing any field on an Item(new or old) in a custom list where this specific dropdown field's text value changes from "Temporary" to "Permanent".

As a background we've added this field a year ago and just moved the position of this field by manually cutting and pasting on the first portion of the *NewForm* and *EditForm*.

I've already checked that there are no workflows that automatically start when an item is edited because they are configured to be manually started.

Could this be a content type issue? Not sure why it automatically changes value as soon as I press save in the Edit Form. I would like to experiment in deleting the portion below from the *EditForm*, but i'm concerned if I delete this in the *EditForm* will I lose any data?

[image: SP_Designer EditForm]

Admittedly, I don't have much knowledge about SP :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to check is any event receiver attached to the list.

```
$spWeb = Get-SPWeb Identity http://Site
$spList = $spWeb.Lists["Custom List"]
$spList.EventReceivers | Select Name, Assembly, Type
```

Comment: unfortunately I am not able to test this as I do not have access on the SP server